# CustomHelper inside {{# each}} block

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a list of "matters."  Each matter has an _id and name.

I have a "transaction." Every transaction belongs to a matter by reference to the matter's _id via a transaction.matterId property.

I'm presently working on a user interface to allow making changes to the transaction, including changing the matter to which the transaction is assigned.  Like this:

```
Enter date:

Select a matter:  (this is the culprit)

Enter the amount:
```

I am using handlebars to generate a Bootstrap select input with an option for each matter - i.e., "Select a matter..."  This is easily done with handlebars {{ # each }} block helper.  All the matters correctly appear as options, and each option's value is correctly assigned.  No problem so far...

However, I want the option whose value matches the transaction.MatterId to be pre-selected since this is an update screen. For that, I invoke my custom "IfEquals" helper inside my {{# each }} block.  The handlebars template is like this:

```
<div>Matter: {{ transaction.matterId}}</div>  <-- I can see the matterId here.
<div class='form-group'>
    <label for="selMatter">Case</label>
    <select required id="selMatter" name="matterId" class="form-control">
        {{# each matters }}
            <option value='{{ _id }}' {{ ifEqual _id ../transaction.matterId "selected" "" }} >{{ name }}</option>
        {{/ each }}
    </select>
</div>
```

The custom helper is this:

```
ifEqual: function (obj, value, trueString, falseString) {
        return ( (obj===value) ? trueString : falseString );
}
```

Let's say the 1st `<div>` shows a transaction.MatterId of "5."  There will be one (and only one) option with a value of "5."

In the handlebars template, I have tried all sorts of possibilities to try to get {{ IfEqual }} to properly compare the 2 values.  I tried the transaction.matterId without the "../" to see if it might be a context problem.  No luck.  I tried using a handlebars subexpression (even with its own helper function).  Nope.

I am not getting the proper values inside the {{ IfEqual }} helper, and for that reason, even though the matching `<option>` is there, I can't make handlebars add the "selected" attribute to it.

Here is what I believe to be the right place to look, but I am not seeing what I am missing.  http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html

Comment: The template appears fine to me. The only reason that I can think of that would prevent this from working would be if `_id` and `transaction.matterId` are of different Types, for example, String and Number.

Comment: @76484 I think they are different types - thus, the toString() casts in my answer, below.  I have tried to use the original {{ ifEqual }} helper in the code above with .toString(), but handlebars rejects it with a parseError.  It doesn't like .toString().  Is there any  out of box fix, or must I still resort to a different, custom helper like below?

Comment: The fix should really be in your data layer, the ID should always be of a consistent type. If this is not possible, then I would recommend creating a `toString` custom helper that will string your values before passing them to the `ifEqual` helper. Alternatively, you could update the `ifEqual` helper to cast `obj` and `value` to strings, but I don't like that approach because it makes the helper a little dishonest.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it, finally.  If anyone comes across this scenario, here's what worked for me:

handlebars template:

```
<div class='form-group'>
   <label for="selMatter">Case</label>
   <select required id="selMatter" name="matterId" class="form-control">
      {{# each matters }}
          {{{ makeOption _id ../transaction.matterId name }}}
      {{/ each }}
   </select>
</div>
```

Here's the {{{ makeOption }}} helper:

```
makeOption: function (optionValue, dataValue, displayText) {
    myOption = "<option value='" + optionValue  + "'";

    if ( optionValue.toString() === dataValue.toString() )
    myOption += " selected";

    myOption += ">" + displayText + "</option>";

    return myOption;
},
```