# Handlebars: Using Parent Variable as a Parameter to a Custom Helper Wrapped in an Each Block

Tags: handlebars.js

Check out ../billerId below.  If I put {{ billerId }} before the {{# each }} block, I can see that billerId is there and defined.

I want to user billerId in my custom helper to see if the option's value should be pre-selected.

```
<select class="searchbar-control col-6 form-control" id="searchbar-select-biller" style="display:none">
    <option value=''>Select a biller...</option>
    {{# each billers }}
        <option value='{{ _id }}' {{ ifEqual _id ../billerId "selected" "" }} >{{ name }}</option>
    {{/ each }}
</select>
```

Here's the helper code:

```
ifEqual: function (obj, value, trueString, falseString) {
   return ( (obj===value) ? trueString : falseString );
},
```

I have tried various syntaxes:  billerId, ../billerId, ../../billerId, {{ billerId }}.

No luck.

Comment: Handlebars _does_ support accessing properties in the parent context. `../billerId` should work. Are you sure the problem is with `../billerId`? I would advise using it in the option text to be sure, ie., by replacing `{{ name }}` with `{{ ../billerId }}` - just to debug.

Comment: I did exactly that before I posted the question.  It doesn't work.  It works by itself, enclosed in braces - i.e., {{ ../billerId }}, but it doesn't work when used without the braces.  The parameter in the helper does not include the braces.

Comment: See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/s17s20vv/. It works just fine. If you are not getting the result you are expecting, I suspect that the issue is that the types of `obj` and `value` are not equal. ie., one is a String and the other a Number.

Comment: Did we not discuss this exact issue less than two weeks ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47916150/3397771 ?

Comment: Good catch!  Yes, I found a work-around (same as below), but rather than cluttering my view with hidden elements, I'd prefer handlebars to handle the variable when generating the html.  It seems like an obvious next feature for handlebars, but since it's not there, I'll just clutter my html and keep moving.

Comment: It's not Handlebars, it's how you've implemented your data and your helper. Just update your helper (or create a new one) that does a lose equality comparison: `return obj == value ? trueString : falseString;`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: You are exactly right!  Again...  My apologies.  The type, ObjectId is not a string, and you in fact helped me with this before.  I have to get used to dealing with this.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, but on researching, I don't think Handlebars allows this type of usage.

Instead, I put the billerId in a hidden span and referenced the span by its id from within javascript.  I assigned "selected" from within the script.